# jQuery to update css height of element after animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/fFYqF/

Basically it's a `h1` above an `h2` with some hidden paragraphs in-between them. This is all contained inside a div which I am trying to make visually centered (horizontally and vertically on the screen. I have used this css on the container div to center it on the page:

```
div#holder {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height:40%;
    width:60%;
    min-width:300px;
}
```

For this to work the width and the height of the div must be specified.
I have 2 problems... first, I don't know the height of the div so I have tried to use jQuery to apply it dynamically:

```
var h = $('#holder').height();
$('#main').css('height', h + 'px');
```

Secondly, I have a further bit of jQuery to animate the paragraphs of text open. This changes the height of the holder div thus rendering the earlier calculated height incorrect and the div is no longer vertically centered.

Is there a way to have the holder div always centered on the page? I.e. it should move up when it is opening.

Please see the fiddle above to see what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated a [branch of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/fFYqF/4/) to use a mixture of using `.animate()` with the height as well as the top position of the element to make it look like its opening up.

Comment: the result looks good but there is a jerk when the `top` attribute is changed. I.e the `top` is not being animated.

Comment: Ahh it seems it works fine in chrome but not so in firefox... The `top` attribute animation seems to be interrupted by something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .animate method instead?  I haven't tested this in a vertical-centered situation like you're describing, but I've used this method to increase the height of my containers when I'm bringing other elements into view.

```
$('#main').animate({height: '+='h }, 'slow');
```

Comment: yes, in fact in my fiddle the animate method is used. This doesn't apply a css height to the parent element though, which is what I want.

Comment: which element are you referring to as the parent?  Main?  Or above main?